# Wordpress role permissions to access (administer) their cases?

Tags: wordpress, civicase, permissions

I have a "volunteer" role that could be assigned as a case role. At the same time I've configured that role with: access_my_cases_and_activities, basic_case_information and other general permissions.

But as is, "volunteer" CMS users can see their assigned cases in dashboard (only if their have activities programed), and when click "administer" or "manage case" it shows that they don't have permissions to access to case.

When I grant permission view_all_contacts, they now can access to the case, but if they search contacts they could see the entire contacts database.

Anyone can help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes I think this general issue has come up before. I don't think a regular role that is not the case manager can access Manage Case unless they have some other permissions, like View/Edit All Contacts.

Comment: I wonder if the Related Permissions extension could help, but suspect it would need extending to be able to work based on Case relationships. https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I understand that case manager should have permissions to edit/eliminate cases, but other roles should have ability to at least see complete details or the activities of the case (at least their own activities). 

In my case, the need is that volunteers could create a case activity (i.e. phone call) inside the case. Is that possible in any other way?

Comment: It's a bit awkward, but if you give them the url they can add activities. For example to create a followup on case 1 for client contact id 19 has url `/civicrm/case/activity?action=add&reset=1&cid=19&caseid=1&atype=14`. They'll get an error when they save since it redirects to manage case, but it does save. It's far from ideal. You could also use the email processor for them to file it on the case via email, e.g. if they put `[case #1]` in the subject. See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/inbound/#autofiling-email-activities-via-emailprocessor

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it :) 
Do you know if some functionality like this could be planned to a future release?

Comment: I was trying this suggestion and in fact with the URL trick I can access to create activity in case. But I'm getting a critical wordpress error after saving... 

I'm not sure how to handle this because I need that volunteers could create their own activities, but it's a risk to allow them to access the entire contacts database.

Should be possible in another way, a kind of rule to copy an activity to a case?